# NTP Servers not Sync with other machines

Tags: ntp

I'm using Linux Debian Wheezy.I have problem to sync time & date between my server & PC,and the ntp servers looks like pointing at itself not internet.

In this case,Fig is my NTP server.

```
root@fig [5156]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 fig.nta-monitor .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

My NTP Server ntp.conf file:

```
root@fig [5155]# less /etc/ntp.conf
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

server 0.my.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.my.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.my.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.my.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 0.asia.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.asia.pool.ntp.org iburst

# ... and use the local system clock as a reference if all else fails
# NOTE: in a local network, set the local stratum of *one* stable server
# to 10; otherwise your clocks will drift apart if you lose connectivity.
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 13

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1 nomodify
```

This is the information for my server & client

```
NTP Server = 192.168.120.104 (Fig) 
Client = 192.168.120.65 (Banana)
```

Please advice.Thanks

Now the issue is why my NTP server used itself as ntp server?

This is what I ping for the pool from NTP server(fig)

```
root@fig [5246]# ping 0.my.pool.ntp.org
PING 0.my.pool.ntp.org (202.45.138.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

But got reply when i ping to yahoo.com

```
root@fig [5247]# ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=1 ttl=39 time=333 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=2 ttl=39 time=332 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=3 ttl=39 time=332 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=4 ttl=39 time=335 ms
^C
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 332.398/333.454/335.464/1.263 ms
```

This is the output when I run ps -ef | grep [n]tp command

```
root@fig [5213]# ps -ef | grep [n]tp
ntp      22526     1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -c /var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp -u 101:108
```

This is the result when I run ntpdate -qu 202.45.138.123 command

```
root@fig [5215]# ntpdate -qu 202.45.138.123
server 202.45.138.123, stratum 2, offset -135.572409, delay 0.06105
 1 Sep 19:18:29 ntpdate[27420]: step time server 202.45.138.123 offset -135.572409 sec
```

Comment: @Rahul Did you mean manually?

Comment: I mean if you turned off `ntpd` can you update the clock by command line?

Comment: @Rahul I think my ntp server need to follow Malaysia — my.pool.ntp.org server,but somehow it point to itself.I already change it manually,but it not sync with client

Comment: You should have one entry in the list from `ntpq -p` for each of your `server` lines. Since you've only got the fudged localhost entry I would say that `ntpd` couldn't resolve the server names when it started. If you restart the daemon does it start working as expected?

Comment: Hi,this is the ntpq -p for my client.Looks like it point to my ntp server.

<pre> 

root@banana [531]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 fig.nta-monitor .INIT.          16 u   55  512    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
root@banana [532]#
</pre>

Comment: There's no point looking at your client until your server is sorted. The output from `ntpq -p` in your question is from _fig_, yes?

Comment: How to add the format inside here?

This is the output for fig ntpq -p

root@fig [5230]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 fig.nta-monitor .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000

Comment: @roaima i only restart using this command /etc/init.d/ntp restart at ntp server,looks like it still point to itself.

Comment: On _fig_ can you resolve the name `0.my.pool.ntp.org` successfully? (Use `ping` or something. It doesn't matter whether the host replies. What's important is that the name resolves to an IP address.)

Comment: Thank you. This is good because it shows that `0.my.pool.ntp.org` currently resolves to `202.45.138.123`. For me, that is a valid NTP server. So, please can you provide output of running this command on _fig_ - `ps -ef | grep [n]tp`. Also the output of `ntpdate -qu 202.45.138.123` (you may need to install the `ntpdate` package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ntpd` is not using your expected configuration file `/etc/ntp.conf`.

Looking at the output of `ps -ef | grep [n]tp` you can see that the configuration file is `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp`, which will probably contain data from DHCP.

There are a couple of [great answers over on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/329596/267016) that explain how to fix this. The summary is that you need to tell *fig* not to configure NTP from DHCP.

> Edit `/etc/dhclient.conf` and uncomment the line "request" with
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, routers, domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
> ```
>
> Especially, if `ntp-servers` is present, remove it. Under some
>   distribution ( aka Fedora ) it is sent by default, so you have to put
>   this line explicitly so that the default is overridden.

You may also need to remove `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp` once you've got a new DHCP lease.

Comment: This is my /etc/dhclient.conf file,
 
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers, domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name, ntp-servers;

Did i need to remove ntp-servers from that file?

Comment: « Especially, if `ntp-servers` is present, remove it »

Comment: is it related with dhcp?Because currently my server(fig) are using static ip.

Comment: « You may also need to remove `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.conf.dhcp` »

Answer (score 0):

When using "NTP server pools" (what you obviously do), use the `pool` keyword instead of `server`.